# TypeError: Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to replicate template in angularjs. like when I click on add button it add new form, when I click on remove button it remove form. When I submit button it send data to backend, but it is giving error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined`, why It is not able to take `$scope.field.field1` value.

Please see [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zPVhPm48i9BceNBfK9Oh?p=preview), it is not working

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div class="col-md-12" style="bottom:10px" >   
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in fields">  
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-4"> 
              <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Field1</label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input data-ng-model='field.field1' class="chosen-select input-md form-control sme-input-box"/>
              </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="col-md-4">          
            <label  class="col-md-12 control-label">Field2</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">            
                <input ng-model='field.field2'  class="chosen-select input-md form-control sme-input-box"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">            
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="removeTemplate($index)">Remove</a>   
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOrder()">Submit</a>   
            </div>                      
        </div>  
      </div>      
      <div class="col-md-3" style="top:5px">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="cloneTemplate()">Add</a>   
      </div>   
    </div>  

</div>
```

**Angularjs**

```
$scope.fields=[
        {
            "field1": "",
            "field2": "",
        }
    ]

    // update and get invoice details
    $scope.cloneTemplate=function(){
        var clone_template={ "field1": "", "field2": ""};
        $scope.fields.push(clone_template);
    }

    $scope.removeTemplate= function(templateIndex){
        $scope.fields.splice(templateIndex,1);
    }

    $scope.updateOrder=function(){
        var updateOrder={
            "field1":$scope.field.field1,
            "field2":$scope.field.field2,
        }

        $http.post(config.server, updateOrder)
        .success(function(response, status){
            console.log(response);                
        })
        .error(function(response, status){
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$scope.field`, read about [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-repeat).

You can pass the $index in your updateOrder function in the view

```
<a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOrder($index)">Submit</a>
```

and use it like this

```
$scope.updateOrder=function(i){
    var updateOrder = {
        "field1":$scope.fields[i].field1,
        "field2":$scope.fields[i].field2,
    };
    .....
};
```

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zPVhPm48i9BceNBfK9Oh?p=preview)

Comment: the `$index` is created by `ng-repeat` so it is also the index of the fields array

Comment: thanks samething I want. I put demo for this in your answer. http://plnkr.co/edit/zPVhPm48i9BceNBfK9Oh?p=preview

Comment: If we want to label button according to requirement, suppose for empty template I want to keep Submit and for non-empty I want to use update. Please see  http://plnkr.co/edit/zPVhPm48i9BceNBfK9Oh?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You had wrong variable name inside `ng-repeat`, It should be `list1` instead of `fields.

**Markup**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in list1">
```

Either way you could rename the scope variable property to `$scope.fields` instead of `$scope.list1`

**Edit**

On submit method you should pass the whole field object to `updateOrder` method, and directly pass that object to `$http` call.

Addtionally you need to add missing $http dependency on your controller function.

**Markup**

```
<a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOrder(field)">Submit</a>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.updateOrder = function(field) {
    //pass the field object as is, because it will have field1 & field2
    var config = { server: '/url'}//should be something
    $http.post(config.server, field)
      .success(function(response, status) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .error(function(response, status) {
        console.log(response);
      })
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xns9Z9LcVdjwKgko4XUL?p=preview)

Comment: yes I corrected code, but when I clicked on submit button  it is giving error..`TypeError: Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined`, please see updated question...

Comment: thanks now it is working, but could you tell me why I am not able to take `$scope.field.field1`.

Comment: suppose if we don't want to send same field name to back-end, when how we will modify..

Comment: @geeks because `ng-repeat` has its own way to render html, while rendering template for each element, it creates a new scope which is prototypically inherited from the currently running scope, so basically `field`  value is not created inside your controller scope, its create in different scope which is child of your current scope.

Comment: @geeks what do you mean by. you don't wanted to send same field to backend?

Comment: o.k, thanks is it possible to access `ng-repeat` controller..?

Comment: @geeks no you cant..you can access the scope, by sending them to with the help of event, like here we are sending `field` scope on `ng-click` event

Comment: If we want to label button according to requirement, suppose for empty template I want to keep Submit and for non-empty I want to use update. Please see  http://plnkr.co/edit/zPVhPm48i9BceNBfK9Oh?p=preview

Comment: @greeks may i know why you removed marked from my answer? Is anything bad with mine answer

Comment: sorry about to forget to tell, please see `koox00`, answer,  we can access the attributes of object using by passing $index in calling method, please see the your demo, which I modify http://plnkr.co/edit/zPVhPm48i9BceNBfK9Oh?p=preview, your answer is correct but It was not my requirement, sorry for that.

Comment: @geeks passing index or passing object is one of the same thing..but out of that i will prefer to pass object..rather than passing index of object.. playing with index wouldn't consider as good approach..think like if you add filter on your `ng-repeat` then above code will messed up like `orderBy`/`search` filter.